# What happens when an app gets supsended?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, mono, background-process

I'm building an app in Unity3D for iOS. I have huge problems with lag, but for some reason the lag disappears for like 5 seconds after I suspend the app by pulling down the iOS top menu or pressing the home button and then get back to the app again.

**What happens when I suspend the app?** How does Unity freeze the app? What functions are called? What happens memory-wise etc?

Comment: im no unity expert, but it sounds like something is spawning tasks continuously so eventually the cpu or gpu cant handle it anymore, and maybe the tasks get removed when the app goes into the background... just speculating

Comment: One of the possible reasons of this kind of lag is instantiating and destory many `GameObject` at once.

Answer (score 1):

When user press home button or leave Application/Game in any way. It will pause whatever is happening in your game. All of the `Update()` `FixedUpdate()` and `LateUpdate()` methods would pause as well. It will call [OnApplicationFocus](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html) and [OnApplicationPause](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) methods at two times (leaving app and coming back to app). You can implement these methods to do Application state specific behaviour. Having said that, lag in game is related to your scripting logic. I would suggest you to Optimise your app for IOS devices. Here are some useful links for you:

- [iOS Specific Optimizations](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-iOS-Optimization.html)
- [Practical Guide to Optimization for Mobiles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileOptimizationPracticalGuide.html)
- [Optimizing graphics performance](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html)
- [IPhone Optimization Tips](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/IPhone_Optimization_Tips)